# Use for loop to search an array of fields to find & replace text

Tags: javascript, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have created an XFA form using Adobe Designer (LiveCycle) which utilizes 25 textfields. I am trying to create a 'Redact' button which, when pressed, will iterate through the 25 fields and search for a name in the string value of each field. If the name is found then it replaces the name with "********" using a global RegExp and if not, moves on to the next field. This is what i've come up with so far, but it isn't working. Can anyone help?

```
var name = nameGlobal.value.toString();
 var regExp = new RegExp(name, "gi");
 var fields = [
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].N_Location.F1.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].N_Witnesses.Notes_2.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].F2.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_4.TextField7").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_5.TextField7").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_6.TextField9").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_7.N_7_2.TextField10").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_7.N_7_4.TextField11").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_7.N_7_6.TextField12").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_7.N_7_8.TextField13").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_7.F4.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F5.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F6.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F20.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.PupilSize.F7.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F8.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F9.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F10.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F11.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.#subform[20].TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_9.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_10.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].F13.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].F14.TextField5").rawValue.toString(),
  xfa.resolveNode("form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Msic_Notes.TextField5").rawValue.toString()
];

 for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if (fields[i] !== null) {
    fields[i] = fields[i].replace(name, "********");
     }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show an example for the `name`? :)

Comment: You also never use your `regExp` variable.

Comment: Perhaps `fields[i] = fields[i].replace(regExp, "********")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why the replace is not working is because `toString()` method returns a new string, not a pointer to the value.

You can fix the problem by putting references of the nodes instead of the rawValue string.

Using some old javascript...

```js
var name = nameGlobal.value; // might need to add toString() back
var regExp = new RegExp(name, "gi");
var fields = [xfa.resolveNode("path_to_node")];
 
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  var rawValue == fields[i];
  if (rawValue !== null) {
    fields[i].rawValue = rawValue.replace(regExp, "********");
  }
}
```

Using modern javascript... (not sure if supported)

```js
let name = nameGlobal.value; // might need to add toString() back
let regExp = new RegExp(name, "gi");
let fields = [ xfa.resolveNode("path_to_node")];
 
for (let field of fields) {
  let rawValue = field.rawValue
  if (!rawValue) { // might need to add the !== null
    field.rawValue = rawValue.replace(regExp, "********");
  }
}
```

I hope that I was helpful :)

Comment: I did something very similar. Thanks for the answer! I wish I could use more modern JS in Designer but it just isn't supported and that is often times very frustrating.

Comment: No problem. I am happy to help :) Your approach looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working and here's what I did:

```
var replace = nameGlobal.value.toString();
var regExp = new RegExp(replace, "gi");
var fields = [
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].N_Location.F1.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].N_Witnesses.Notes_2.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].F2.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_4.TextField7",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_5.TextField7",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_6.TextField9",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_7.N_7_2.TextField10",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_7.N_7_4.TextField11",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_7.N_7_6.TextField12",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_7.N_7_8.TextField13",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_7.F4.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F5.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F6.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F20.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.PupilSize.F7.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F8.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F9.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F10.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.F11.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_8.ClinicalNOtes.#subform[20].TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_9.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Notes_10.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].F13.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].F14.TextField5",
  "form1.#subform[3].#subform[4].Msic_Notes.TextField5",
  ];

for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    var val = xfa.resolveNode(fields[i]).rawValue;
    if (val !== null) {
        if (val.search(regExp) !== -1) {
            xfa.resolveNode(fields[i]).rawValue = val.replace(regExp, "*******").toString();
      }
    }
  }
```